# How to create a hash of arrays or hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I have a file named Jobs.conf which contains:

```
JobName: A  
JobSize: 100
JobArrival:1
JobExe:100  

JobName: B
JobSize: 100
JobArrival:2
JobExe:100 

JobName: C
JobSize: 100
JobArrival:3
JobExe:100

JobName: D
JobSize: 100
JobArrival:4
JobExe:100
```

Is it possible to read this file so each Job is stored in an array and then the 4 arrays are stored in a hash?  Would it make more sense to store this as a hash of hashes and is that possible?

Comment: You can do either. There are plenty of resources on how to create hashes of arrays or hashes of hashes. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: The best way to store the data depends on how you intend to use it, and on what the data itself looks like. For example, I would probably create an array of hashes, but if each job name is guaranteed to be unique, it might be easier to make a hash of hashes where the top-level keys are job names. So, how do you intend to use the data?

Comment: @scrappedcola I am aware you can create a hash of hashes my question is how to do this whilst reading from a file. I can't work out how to store the 4 lines and then when it hits job B start a new hash.  I can only store all the information into a single array.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The job names are guaranteed to be unique, this is why i also thought a hash of hashes would be better.  I am trying to create a memory manager so these jobs will be passed into a fake ram file that i will create and then depending on the type of partition selected it will run a simulation of "processing" the jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to set `$/` (the [input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR)) properly:

> This influences Perl's idea of what a "line" is. Works like awk's RS
>   variable, including treating empty lines as a terminator if set to the
>   null string (an empty line cannot contain any spaces or tabs). You may
>   set it to a multi-character string to match a multi-character
>   terminator, or to `undef` to read through the end of file. Setting it
>   to `"\n\n"` means something slightly different than setting to `""`,
>   if the file contains consecutive empty lines. Setting to `""` will
>   treat two or more consecutive empty lines as a single empty line.
>   Setting to `"\n\n"` will blindly assume that the next input character
>   belongs to the next paragraph, even if it's a newline.

Then we just take advantage of how the records are laid out by `split`-ing directly into a hash reference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

local $/ = "";
my @jobs;

while (<DATA>) {
    push(@jobs, {split(/:\s*|\n/)});
}

dd(\@jobs);

__DATA__
JobName: A
JobSize: 100
JobArrival:1
JobExe:100

JobName: B
JobSize: 100
JobArrival:2
JobExe:100

JobName: C
JobSize: 100
JobArrival:3
JobExe:100

JobName: D
JobSize: 100
JobArrival:4
JobExe:100
```

Or just:

```
my @jobs = map { {split(/:\s*|\n/)} } <DATA>;
```

Output:

```
[
  { JobArrival => 1, JobExe => 100, JobName => "A", JobSize => 100 },
  { JobArrival => 2, JobExe => 100, JobName => "B", JobSize => 100 },
  { JobArrival => 3, JobExe => 100, JobName => "C", JobSize => 100 },
  { JobArrival => 4, JobExe => 100, JobName => "D", JobSize => 100 },
]
```

An array of hashes (the previous example) would be my preference, but if you wanted a hash of hashes, you'd need to modify the code slightly:

```
my %jobs;

while (<DATA>) {
    my %temp = split(/:\s*|\n/);
    $jobs{delete($temp{JobName})} = \%temp;
}

dd(\%jobs);
```

Output:

```
{
  A => { JobArrival => 1, JobExe => 100, JobSize => 100 },
  B => { JobArrival => 2, JobExe => 100, JobSize => 100 },
  C => { JobArrival => 3, JobExe => 100, JobSize => 100 },
  D => { JobArrival => 4, JobExe => 100, JobSize => 100 },
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed.  Thank you so much.

Comment: How can i set local $/ back to its default value?  Once i have read this file I wish to read another file and because of the local $/ it is not storing correctly.  I have tried setting it to undef and "\n\n" but it still does not store the next hash correctly due to there being no paragraph spaces.

Comment: @SilentUK The default is newline, but you probably just want to [localize](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) `$/` to a block...